# Deserialize JSON having keys with CamelCase and snake_case naming in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am receiving a `json` file via api, that `json` file will be converted into a class that I cant touch and has around 400 properties. the `json` is using for the key names **CamelCase** and in the same `json` some keys are in the format of **snake_case**.
I am currently using [System.Text.Json](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/d0d704a2e0b86d37cf62591514325f259acc8435/src/libraries/System.Text.Json) but open to change to [Newtonsoft.json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is needed.
I tried to create a `JsonSnakeCaseNamingPolicy` class (only  converting the property names to snake_case) and used in the `JsonSerializerOptions` like this:

```cs
var deserializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = new JsonSnakeCaseNamingPolicy()
};
var flexImport = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<FlexImport>>(input.MappedObjectJson, deserializeOptions);
```

But then the properties in **CamelCase** don't get populated. Any idea on how to achieve this situation?

This the `json` sample:

```
[{\"BatchId\":123,\"Title_Id\":123,\"CurrentNumber\":\"aa705128\",\"address\":\"122 BLACKSGATE EN\",\"curr_interest_rate\":4},{\"BatchId\":2,\"Title_Id\":1,\"CurrentNumber\":\"27705128\",\"address\":\"90 ARMA DR\",\"curr_interest_rate\":5},{\"BatchId\":2,\"Title_Id\":2,\"CurrentNumber\":\"30877674\",\"address\":\"6485 N SIN CIR\",\"curr_interest_rate\":4}]"
```

And here is part of the destination class:

```cs
public class FlexImport 
{
    public long BatchId { get; set; }
    public long TitleId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public decimal? CurrInterestRate { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use JSON attributes

```
public class FlexImport 
{
    public long BatchId { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("Title_Id")]
    public long TitleId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("curr_interest_rate")]
    public decimal? CurrInterestRate { get; set; }

}
```

Etc. Adjust as needed.

Comment: I can't touch that class

Comment: In that case, then consider using newtonsoft and using JObject.Parse. This will allow you access your data through their name in json. For example to access Title_Id myJObject[0]["Title_Id"]